# Getting the last sub-category of a product in magento

Tags: php, magento

I having been searching for days to get the last subcategory of a product in magento.

Actually what i have to do is display the last subcategory the product is placed in. for example i have plastic and glass as products. I want to display the last subcategory i.e cups or plates.

|Party
--|boys
----|batman
--------|cups
-----------|plastic
-----------|glass 
--------|plates
----|Superman

i have edited the list.phtml file, i can get the category id's and name from the array but they are all mixed up. So there is no way to figure out which one is the last category.
Is there any default functionality in magento? or someone be kind enough to help me out?
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "last category", the last category that was assigned to it? The furthest down the category tree?

Comment: yes, please see the map i have edited just now. You can have a better understanding of what i mean.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

Okay, from your description it sounds like you want to get the child categories from the current category you're in. (I.E. Get `cups` and `plates` while in `batman` category view).

The following should be just about as little as you need to get the current children.

```
<?php
    $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
    $children = Mage::registry( 'current_category' )->getChildrenCategories();
?>
<ul>
    <?php foreach( $children as $child ): ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($child); ?>"><?php echo $child->getName() ?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

**Previous Answer(s)**

It's a little roundabout, but this can get you the parent category id from a product object.

```
//If you don't have a product to start with, load by ID.
$_product = Mage::getModel( 'catalog/product' )->load($id);

//Assign Category Model
$categoryModel = Mage::getModel( 'catalog/category' );

//Get Array of Category Id's with Last as First (Reversed)
$_categories = array_reverse( $_product->getCategoryIds() );

//Get Parent Category Id
$_parentId = $categoryModel->load($_categories[0])->getParentId();

//Load Parent Category
$_category = $categoryModel->load($_parentId);

//Do something with $_category
echo $_category->getName();
```

It works better when the product only has one category Id assigned to it. You may not get the category you want if multiple categories have been assigned to that one product.

Also, you can get it a slightly quicker way, but this method doesn't work if the product was searched for:

```
$_category = Mage::getModel( 'catalog/category' )->load( Mage::registry( 'current_category' )->getParentId() );
```

I didn't test the line above, but it should work. Only if the product was reached by browsing through the categories though.

Comment: Sorry but this isnt what i need. I need to get the last child of the category this product is in. Or is there some way i can get the category name by level?

Comment: Please clarify your question so I can better understand then. You can get the level and position of a category by `$category->getLevel()` and `$category->getPosition()`. This will give you the tier and sort order, respectively.

Comment: Actually i know about the getlevel method, but thats not enough. for instance if the product was in some level other than the condition we built it for. I want a builtin magento functionality that can  get me the subcategory name which have the product in it.

Comment: In your description, you say `glass` and `plastic` are products. Do you want to get BOTH `cups` and `plates` category? Are `glass` and `plastic` assumed to be in another category as well (i.e. `ROOT_CATEGORY/cups/glass`)? Or are `glass` and `plastic` not actually products?

Comment: in the example above, glass and plastic are both products. and Yes it can be assigned to 1 or more categories. I just want to retrieve "cups", and not plates if the product is not assigned to it.

Comment: And what page are you in specifically? The product view page for glass/plastic, category view page for cups?

Comment: We want it on the list.phtml page. To be specific we want them on the category list view of "Batman". So our products i.e plastic and glass, will be arranged according to cups and plates. and we can have headings and separaters to separate them apart.  Thanks for your help